# Flash Builder 4 - Flash Player failed to connect to debugger

Tags: apache-flex, flash, debugging, builder, progress

I just finished my installation of Adobe Flash Builder 4. I've definitely installed the most recent flash player from Adobe's website onto my computer. Also, in the run configurations of flash builder 4, I changed the source path from the .html file to the .swf file that is generated. I don't need to test it in a web browser, I just want to run the swf in flash player.

I only have 1 .as file in my actionscript project and there is no code written in it other than the package, class and main function statements. When I run the .html file, it runs fine, and debugs fine. However, when I switch the source path to the .swf file, it runs fine but **doesn't debug**!

When I debug it, the progress gets stuck at 57% and it says "Waiting for Adobe Flash Player to connect to debugger..." in the "Progress" tab. After a few minutes a window pops up that says:

"Failed to connect. The session has timed out. Ensure that you have run the application with debugging on and that I have the debugger version of flash player."

What can I do to fix this? I am on an intel Mac running OS 10.6.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you installed the most recent Flash Player, but you don't say if you by that mean the debug player. The "Flash Player 10.1 Plugin content debugger" and "Flash Player 10.1 Projector content debugger" can be downloader at http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've downloaded 10.1 the debug player.

Comment: OK. Since you say "I don't need to test it in a web browser, I just want to run the swf in flash player", I assume you also installed the "Flash Player 10.1 Projector content debugger" and has made sure it is used to run the swf?

Comment: I've definitely installed it. I'm not sure that it is the one that is used to run the swf which may be the issue. How can I choose it in Flash Builder?

Comment: I don't know if you can choose it in Flash Builder or not, but you can select it as the default application for swf files ("Get Info" on a swf file in Finder and then select "Flash Player Debugger" under "Open with:"). Also, I believe it will be used if you leave it running, having it open and running, when you run the swf from Flash Builder.

Comment: Perfect it works! Thanks very much. Im guessing there is no way to run different players depending on if you "run" or "debug" your script?

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem
http://blog.air4android.com/?p=59

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly that symptom.

I cleaned all related projects, removed bin-debug and bin-release, cleaned the cache, reinstalled the debug version of the player.  It didn't help.  I was about to reinstall FlashBuilder.

Then I displayed the javascript console.  I saw there is a syntax error in my index.template.  As a result, the application was never started, so the screen remained blank and the debugger failed to connect.

I fixed the silly error and it worked again!  Basically, that message tells you the application failed to start.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using Chrome. At time of writing Flash Player debugger does not work in Chrome.

I had this problem and simply switched the web browser to Safari in Flash Builder preferences.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me finally was copying the **swfobject.js** to the bin-debug folder. I don't know why it wasn't there, but that fixed the problem.

you do, of course, have to run a flash debugger version in your browser.